# Не могу создавать новые файлы внутри папок "компьютера" Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

В пределах компьютера - там, где системные папки, - нет прав создавать папки, файлы - копировать тоже нельзя в них. Права принадлежат root'у.
Соответственно, в Apache - var/www - я тоже не могу ничего вставить.
Как это поправить?

Comment: А в каталоге под `~` писать получается?

Comment: Это как? Объясните, пожалуйста, а то я пока в Unix профан )

Comment: Через Терминал тоже пишет: "Отказано в доступе".

Comment: Ну, в домашнем каталоге? В юникс-системах принято, чтобы пользователь писал только свой домашний каталог.

Comment: Да, там получается.

Comment: Значит вам надо стать рутом. см. команды `su` или `sudo`, правда пароль рута знать надо

Comment: Ну, а остальные каталоги зарезервированы для root, администратора системы. Так что всё правильно. Если вы знаете административный пароль, вы можете делать что угодно при помощи sudo, но тогда ответственность за работоспособность системы ложится на вас.

Comment: Мой пароль таки подошел, и я смог создать папку через Терминал, но как мне настроить доступы на запись, или вернее - как я мог бы делать тоже самое через Nautilus (файловый менеджер системы)?

Comment: Почитайте про `chmod` и `chown`.

Comment: **Права принадлежат root'у** - это странно, т.к. права на эту папку должны принадлежать пользователю apache. Посмотрите файл /etc/password - есть там такой пользователь ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> я тоже не могу ничего вставить

Кто этот "я" ? Когда ставим апач, то создаётся папка /var/www. Эта папка имеет ВЛАДЕЛЬЦА и ГРУППУ. И этот владелец (как правило - apache) и группа имеют ПРАВА. На чтение, запись...  А Вы - кто ? Если у Вас есть желание писать в эту папку, то можете включить себя в группу, которая владеет этой папкой. Делается это командой:

```
sudo usermod "я" -G apache
```

Можете забрать этот каталог себе командой:

```
sudo chown -R "я":users /var/www
```

Но тогда сервер apache потеряет возможность работать с этим каталогом. 
Вы сначала разберитесь с тем, что Вам на самом деле нужно, а потом пытайтесь что-то менять. По умолчанию, после установки апача, все права и так настроены нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей!